# cron job in google app engine not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have taken the basic python 3 tutorial website on flask from this [google cloud tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app) and I am able to set this up and the website works just fine.

In addition , I also wanted to run a python script  which runs everyday to collect some data, but the cron job just doesn't work. I also added login: admin to restrict anyone to directly use that url

**cron.yaml**

```
cron:
- description: test dispatch vs target
  url: /cronapp
  schedule: every 5 hours
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

handlers:
- url: /cronapp
  script: cronapp.py
  login: admin
```

I am calling this as http://myproject.appspot.com/cronapp also doesn't work and returns a 404.
what am I doing wrong ? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app.yaml file is mixing up the standard environment [Handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) element into a [flexible environment configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml), so it is probably ignored. You can probably see the cron requests in the app's logs in the developer console (likely with errors, though).

You need to add a handler for `/cronapp` *inside your app* code, not in `app.yaml`. Not entirely sure how you do that (I'm still using only standard environment), it depends on your app and/or its framework. Take a look at the [Hello World code review](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review) for a flask example.

**Update:**

I may not be entirely correct, I based my answer on documentation but I just noticed some inconsistencies (I sent some documentation feedback to Google for it).

The flexible environment [Securing URLs for cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#securing_urls_for_cron) (which appears mostly  copied from [the standard environment equivalent](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#securing_urls_for_cron)) mentions a couple of solutions:

- one indeed based on the `login: admin` option to `handler`:

> You can restrict a URL by adding `login: admin` to the handler
>   configuration section in `app.yaml`. For more information see
>   [Securing URLs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#security)

But `handler` is not mentioned in the [Configuring your App with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) and the [Securing URLs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#security) is pointing to an inexistent tag. So I'm not sure if this is indeed working or not.

- the second one is based on the `X-Appengine-Cron` header (same as in the standard environment):

> Requests from the Cron Service will also contain a HTTP header:
>
> ```
> X-Appengine-Cron: true
> ```
>
> The `X-Appengine-Cron` header is set internally by Google App Engine.
>   If your request handler finds this header it can trust that the
>   request is a cron request. If the header is present in an external
>   user request to your app, it is stripped, except for requests from
>   logged in administrators of the application, who are allowed to set
>   the header for testing purposes.

But in [Removed headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled#removed_headers) it is mentioned that:

> In addition, some selected headers that match the following pattern
>   are removed from the request:
>
> - `X-Appengine-*`

It's unclear if this extends to `X-Appengine-Cron` or not. It's worth a try. This is my check in the (standard env, webapp2-based) cron handler code:

```
    if self.request.headers.get('X-AppEngine-Cron') is None:
        self.abort(403)  # HTTPForbidden
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Cron works fine if I put the handler directly in the app. But I don't want the outside world to call this URL. This should only be accessible via cron. Any ideas on how to restrict that ?

Comment: Thanks Dan for the detailed response. I tested with X-app engine-cron in the headers as you said but looks like it isn't sent with the header in the flexible environment. I will open up a ticket with google.

Comment: I am not sure what has happened now . but a fresh deployment on a fresh new project seems to have worked with X-AppEngine-Cron solution . Thanks again for your help.