# Google app engine cron returning 404 for node js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron

I am trying to run a cron in google app engine which should run a node.js script every 2 minute but i always get 404 error in the log. I see the cron is running every 2 minute but its not finding the script *cronRun.js*. Below is the relevant part of the code.

**cron.yaml**

```
cron:
- description: "daily summary job"
  url: /task
  schedule: every 2 minutes
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /task
  script: cronRun.js
```

**log:**

> "GET /task" 404

By this I see that I am not defining the path correctly.

**Below is the file structure**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried making a request to the **/task** endpoint directly, without going through the Cron job? Maybe the problem is in your application and not in Cron.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [404 from cron job on google app engine django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776773/404-from-cron-job-on-google-app-engine-django-app)

Comment: @Yandrak3 Thanks! it worked. I am very new to node js and google app engine. I never thought to check if the endpoints work. Probably you can add your comments in answer so that I can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making a request to the /task endpoint directly, without going through the Cron job?

The problem may be related to the application itself and not the Cron job, so I would recommend you to test it by accessing your App Engine application with the **/task** endpoint.

If it does not work, the issue is definitely caused by the application and not Cron.